# Matching string without using loop

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching

I have 2 data sets.

```
a <- c("adidas shoes","hot tea","pizza","hill station")
b <- c("shoes","plastic cup","pizza","I love to go to hill","travelling in motor van",
       "buy adidas shoes","run using adidas shoes")
```

I want to match each word from each sentence of the 1st vector with all the elements of the second vector and choose the one where maximum number of words match.

For that I have used the below code:

```
a_split <- unlist(strsplit(a[1,], " "))
b_split <- unlist(strsplit(b[1,], " "))
a$match_perc[1] <- length(intersect(a_split, b_split))/length(a_split)*100
```

so essentially what I am trying to do here is, match both 'adidas' and 'shoes' [ the 1st element of the vector 'a'] with all the elements of vector 'b' and finally come up with the best matching percentage and repeat this for all the elements of 'a'. In case the percentage comes same, we will always take the highest percentage. Essentially, for every sentence, I will have only one matching sentence as one matching percentage. I case we have the same highest percentage, we will take the 1st match.

The expected output is below:

```
a <- c("adidas shoes","hot tea","pizza","hill station")
Matching_String <- c("buy adidas shoes","NA","pizza","I love to go to hill")
match_perc <- c(100,0,100,50)
final_op <- data.frame(a,Matching_String,match_perc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::map` functions also:

```
library(purrr)
match_perc <- map2_dbl(a, Matching_String, function(a, b) {
  a_split <- unlist(strsplit(a, " "))
  b_split <- unlist(strsplit(b, " "))
  length(intersect(a_split, b_split))/length(a_split)*100
})
final_op <- data.frame(a,Matching_String,match_perc)
final_op
             a      Matching_String match_perc
1 adidas shoes     buy adidas shoes        100
2      hot tea                   NA          0
3        pizza                pizza        100
4 hill station I love to go to hill         50
```

Also look at `stringr::str_extract_all` function for such string extraction

Comment: You have assumed that `Matching_String` already exists, which is probably not the case. I admit it's somewhat confusing, though.

Comment: When i try to use 'map2_dbl' it's showing me an error 

Error: .x (579) and .y (4) are different lengths

Answer (score 0):

The output of `strsplit` as lists is useful.

```
as <- strsplit(a, " ")
bs <- strsplit(b, " ")
```

You could create a matching matrix of these lists by vectorizing your function and using `outer`.

```
matchFun <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)) / length(x) * 100
mx <- outer(as, bs, Vectorize(matchFun))
```

Then put the maximums into vectors.

```
m <- apply(mx, 1, which.max)  # the maximum column of each row

z <- unlist(apply(p, 1, function(x) x[which.max(x)]))  # maximum percentage
z[z == 0] <- NA  # this gives you the NA if you want it
```

Finally put the result into a data frame.

```
data.frame(a, Matching_String=b[m], match_perc=z)

#              a      Matching_String match_perc
# 1 adidas shoes     buy adidas shoes        100
# 2      hot tea                shoes         NA
# 3        pizza                pizza        100
# 4 hill station I love to go to hill         50
```

---

***Data***

```
a <- c("adidas shoes","hot tea","pizza","hill station")
b <- c("shoes","plastic cup","pizza","I love to go to hill","travelling in motor van",
       "buy adidas shoes","run using adidas shoes")
```

Comment: Since my data set is quite long, the 'outer' function is taking forever.
Also what is 'm' in  Matching_String=b[m] ?

When i try to use 'map2_dbl' it's showing me an error

Error: `.x` (579) and `.y` (4) are different lengths

Comment: Oh, I forgot to paste the line of code for `m`, fixed now. I gave you a solution for the data you provided. If it doesn't work for your original data, you should make a better example, as I can hardly guess them. And there's no `map2_dbl` in my code?